# Heroku Request Interupted django admin

Tags: django, heroku, django-admin

Sometimes i get this error in **papertrail** while working in django admin.

```
sock=client at=error code=H18 desc="Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/ro/admin/something
```

app is hosted on **heroku**.

Weird thing is that i dont know how to reproduce this. 
I rulled out large image reason.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if it's a network issue. Appears to be on the client side.

Read this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h18-request-interrupted

And this question:

[How should I interpret Heroku H18 errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704777/how-should-i-interpret-heroku-h18-errors)